# Angular 7 SSR and Firebase deployment

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, angular7

I'm at a loss here:

I have followed a few tutorials for getting SSR (Server Side Rendering) to work for an Angular 7 application. Most of the documentation is out of date (Angular 5 or older)

I have been able to piece it together and run an SSR Angular 7 application, mostly by using [Angular's documentation.](https://angular.io/guide/universal)

Where I can't figure out the next steps are using the server / ssr in firebase.

I see what appear to be my two folders for the Browser and Server:

Browser has the files:

```
assets
3rdpartylicenses.txt
favicon.ico
fontawesome-webfont.674f50d287a8c48dc19b.eot
fontawesome-webfont.912ec66d7572ff821749.svg
fontawesome-webfont.af7ae505a9eed503f8b8.woff2
fontawesome-webfont.b06871f281fee6b241d6.ttf
fontawesome-webfont.fee66e712a8a08eef580.woff
index.html
main.0230770c5815571b2c78.js
polyfills.1103de3048579260ddf9.js
runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js
styles.f0a317c20d67d98dca61.css
```

And server has the files:

```
main.js
main.js.map
```

in my firebase.json I can point firebase serve to the browser folder and I get only a white page on localhost:5000; No errors or useful information

What does it take to get the express server / Angular App to actually work in Firebase Hosting?

(Firebase hosting does work as a SPA for this application)